# Blender 2.8 texture paint brush presets

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm texturing a model, and I used a texture stencil to try it out. Now I can't make a new brush preset for solid colors or other textures, the only way I can do this is deleting the first texture. I think there is a way to make new brush presets but there is no `+` to add a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tool properties panel with the current brush displayed, look for the number next to the name of the brush. Clicking it will create a single user copy, and in this copy you can delete the connection to the texture.
[image]